# How to execute SharePoint Rest API without using Azure AD or Username and password

Tags: c#, sharepoint

This is the code I am trying to execute :-

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const siteUrl = 'url';
const libraryName = 'Pages';

const pageData = {
  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Publishing.ReusableHTMLItem' },
  'Title': 'New Page Title',
  'LayoutWebpartsContent': '<div>Page Content Goes Here</div>',
  'Publish': true
};

const headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
  'Authorization': 'Access Token'
 };
   
fetch(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${libraryName}')
 /AddValidateUpdateItemUsingPath()`,    
 {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: headers,
     body: JSON.stringify(pageData)
  })
 .then(response => {
  if (response.status === 201) {
     console.log('Page created successfully.');
  } else {
    console.error('Page creation failed.');
  }
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
 });
```

Need a way to get the Access token for the Authorization for header without Azure AD or Username and password.

Or Else need another way to create a page in a SharePoint using Rest API without Azure AD or Username and password.

Tried with Username and password there is some restriction in the Microsoft 365 Admin Center.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to obtain the Token through Azure AD or Username and password before you can send a Rest api request.